# Spring Boot Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building some **API** with **Spring Boot**, but I get some errors about Content-Type when I try to query with Postman.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/xml", produces = "application/json")
    String verify(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload, HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

I don't understand where there is the problem.

**I noticed that the error disappears when I remove @RequestBody as parameter of method. Why?**

I would simply:

- send XML to API
- receive JSON from API

[image: Postman call of API]

Comment: change consumes = "text/xml" to consumes = "application/xml"

Comment: Sorry, not working. See my last update in the main post.

Comment: Can you show the Accept header from the request as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting and Error related to `Content-Type`, then I surely assume that you use *HTTP REST* as mean to communicate between your components.

The `Content-Type` is related to **Content Negotiation** topic within *HTTP REST*.

**Content Negotiation** topic within *HTTP REST* means that clients and services must agree on representation media type. i.e they need to agree how to communicate with each other, what will be the content of each payload that is sent and received between the parties.

Client specifies what it wants through ***`Accept` header***

Server specifies what produces through ***`Content-Type` header***

Comment: You are right,i set  `@RequestMapping(value = "/finding", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })`
check your produces value

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in your application.properties:

logging.file = myapp.log

Restart your server, make a request. Check myapp.log to find what is failing.
For me, I got this error:

---

2018-05-08 07:08:34.404  WARN 348 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-5] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.atta.entity.User]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.atta.entity.State)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [`jackson-dataformat-xml`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) dependency to your classpath or if you are using a build tool to maven (pom.xml) or gradle (build.gradle).

**NOTE**: You can support both `text/xml` and `application/xml` by doing `... consumes = { "text/xml", "application/xml" } ...`.

**NOTE:** Instead of strings you can use [MediaType](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) members: `... consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML } ...`

Comment: I will try to add the dependency. For the other advices, haven't you seen the posted code? There are already consumes/produces attributes. MediaType Constants or pure String don't change the final result.

Comment: @AndreaLimoli I updated my answer to make it clearer. Sorry for the confusion I introduced previously. I wanted to point out that you can consume multiple content types referring to XML and also that you can use MediaType instead of writing strings. These are side notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Http Header Content-Type to text/xml in your postman. 
You can also check what is the Content-Type header going currently in Chrome DevTools -> Network Tab -> Click on your request -> Headers Tab.

Comment: On Postman the content type will be automatically inserted in header according to the body format you choose. There is not a problem to discover what content type is sent because Spring answers clearly. The content type that I pass in the request is not supported. Why?

Comment: Not sure how postman works, but 415 error clearly indicate that Content-Type what is expected in Service and what is sent from you client is not matching. Try Chrome devtools to figure out what is the Content Type sent in the request header. Also try using cURL

Answer (score 0):

Change

1) value of `header` of postman request to `application/json`

2) from

```
consumes = "text/xml"
```

to

```
"application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

In mycase I had incorrect JSON Property mapping which resulted in same exception

```
@JsonProperty("Total")
private List<XXX> SafeMembers;
```

I mapped JSON property to Total instead of SafeMembers. I changed as below

```
@JsonProperty("SafeMembers")
private List<XXX> SafeMembers;
```